# Vue.js Property or method "addToCart" is not defined on the instance

Tags: vue.js, error-handling

I am trying to make a component but it is saying that I have not defined "addToCart".  I have defined it in the same component, but I continue to get the same error?

```
Vue.component("solid-back",{
    template: `
    <div>
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <img :src="image">
        <h3>Price</h3>
        <p>{{price}}</p>
        <ul id="deets">
            <li v-for="detail in details">{{ detail }}</li>
        </ul>
            <button v-on:click="addToCart" 
                id="btn_add-to-cart">
                Add to Cart
            </button>
            <button id="btn_buy-now">
                Buy Now
            </button>
    </div>
    `,
    data() {
        return {
            title: "Solid Back Black Chair",
            image: "./photos/chairs/solidblack.jpg",
            price: "$34.00",
            details: ["3 feet tall", "Oakwood", "8 pounds"],
        }
    },
    method: {
        addToCart() {
            this.$emit("add-to-cart")
        }
    }
})
```

This is the warning I continue to get

`[Vue warn]: Property or method "addToCart" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define methods in Vue, the property key is `methods`. It looks like your `methods` property is misspelled (singular) `method`.

Changing it to `methods: { ... }` should work:

```
    methods: {
        addToCart() {
            this.$emit("add-to-cart")
        }
    }
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24057546).

Answer (score 1):

Hi `Terrance` Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Remember how `objects` work. There is key and associated property with it

```
const foo  = {
  name: 'Satyam'
}
```

Now `foo` is an `object` which has a property `name`.

So when you try to log it `console.log(foo.name)` you will get `satyam`
But what if you tried to log something which doesn't exist like `foo.age`, you will get nothing as `foo` does not have any property called as `age` with it.

In a same way `Vue` is also an `object` here which has a property `methods`, when you write a `fn` inside that `methods` property you can see it like this `Vue -> methods -> yourFunction`

Now in your question you created a `fn` inside a property name `method`, which is ok as it's not an error and you can add any property to a `object` but `Vue` template which is `binded` with `vue` predefined `properties` such as `methods / computed / data` etc will not recognise it. So you must need to add your `method/ function` inside the `methods` property to make the `template` recognise it.

That's what Vue error is explaining -

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "addToCart" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
>   reactive, either in the data option or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

Property / method `addToCart` is not defined but reference during render means - In your `template` you are trying execute a method/ fn name `addToCart` which it can't find in `Vue available properties` as `method` is not `binded` to `template/ html` - It's looking for a function `addToCart` in vue available methods - `Vue.methods.addTocart` ?? which doesn't exist

I hope it helps !!!